# MySQL Create Table Error Syntax

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error, mariadb

Hello i am having an issue when trying to create a table inside of my database `webhostc_MyRadContactForm`

When i try to execute the statement below in phpMyAdmin i get this error

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts (
-> ContactID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
-> ContactName VARCHAR(100),
-> ContactEmail VARCHAR(100),
-> ContactLeastFavoriteColor VARCHAR(10)
-> ContactDateCreated DATETIME
-> );
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-> ContactID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>       -> ContactName VARCHA' at line 2

Also phpMyAdmin flags these lines:

[image]

My server is running: 10.0.22-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma just after `ContactLeastFavoriteColor VARCHAR(10)` and those arrows, `->`, are not supposed to be there. The following is the correct syntax for creating your table:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts (
  ContactID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ContactName VARCHAR(100),
  ContactEmail VARCHAR(100),
  ContactLeastFavoriteColor VARCHAR(10),
  ContactDateCreated DATETIME
);
```

Good luck!!

Comment: The error message complains about the `->` symbols, not the missing comma.

Comment: @Barmar I second that, that's why I didn't add them to my answer.

Comment: I noticed that, but you could have mentioned that this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. Those `->` symbols aren't part of SQL syntax. They're the prompts that the `MySQL monitor` prints when you enter a multi-line query. You can't copy them into PhpMyAdmin.
2. You're missing a comma at the end of the `ContactLeastFavoriteColor` line.